# Запрос вывода определенных значений

Tags: sql, сортировка, запрос, mariadb

Здравствуйте. Интересует такой вопрос. 
Есть таблица допустим со структурой: name, parent, price и т.д.
Задача: вывести сначала в таблице значения с определенными значениями parent (например, 1,2,3), а потом значения со всеми остальными значениями parent (т.е. 4, 5, 6..)
Выглядеть это должно примерно как-то так:

[image: таблица]
Пробовала делать запрос следующим способом, но результата никакого не дало:

```
SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` ORDER BY parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747) ASC
```

Движок mariaDB
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что исправить или как правильно составить запрос...

Comment: Почему ASC-то? DESC..

Comment: При изменении ASC на DESC ничего не поменялось. И разве эти значения не отвечают просто на порядок сортировки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` 
ORDER BY 
case when parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747) then 0 else 1 end, parent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` ORDER BY parent ASC
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` ORDER BY 2
```

Если нужен фильтр на значения, то

```
SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747) ORDER BY parent ASC

SELECT * FROM 'modx_site_content' WHERE parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM 'modx_site_content' WHERE parent NOT IN (54721, 55450, 54747)
```

Comment: Первый вариант не подходит, т.к. значения довольно разные (т.е. допустим надо выделить значения сначала с parent = 54731, 547277 , а потом остальное. Второй вариант просто выдаст ошибку 1054, т.к. обращаемся по несуществующему столбцу...

Comment: @Yumie, обновил пост

Comment: Третий вариант, выводит только значения, которые мы указываем в IN. А необходимо, чтоб он выводил все остальное после этих значений...

Comment: Тогда разбивайте запрос и [используйте](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) `UNION` : `SELECT * FROM 'modx_site_content' WHERE parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747)  UNION SELECT * FROM 'modx_site_content' WHERE parent NOT IN (54721, 55450, 54747) `

Comment: И так я пробовала. Заковырка в том, что в объединенных запросах должно быть по одинаковому количеству значений. Т.е. в первом если будет 50, а во втором 500 - он выдаст ошибку.

Comment: У меня работает с разным числом выборок. Странное поведение... Проверяли?

Comment: При вводе запроса phpMyAdmin выводит ошибку: Unexpected ordering of clauses. Сам запрос: SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` where parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747) union SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE parent not IN (54721, 55450, 54747)

Comment: попробуйте `UNION ALL`. Возможно есть проблеммы с уникумом других полей

Comment: Прикопался к синтаксису, хотя по идее запрос введен верно: SELECT * FROM 'modx_site_content' WHERE parent IN (54721, 55450, 54747)
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 'modx_site_content' WHERE parent NOT IN (54721, 55450, 54747)

Comment: Копировали? Я кавычки поменял для нормального отображения поста...

Comment: Ой, простите :) Получилось. Благодарю

Comment: Силь ву пле. Закину в пост - ставьте лайки